# Sort a DATA FRAME according to column(s), applying NATURAL sorting

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

The title is self-explanatory, I know how to sort a data frame according to column(s), and I know how to perform natural sorting on a variable, but I cannot sort a data frame using natural sorting.

Check the MWE below:

```
mydf <- data.frame(name=c("B","C","A","E","F","Z","U","D","G","J"), 
                   section=c(NA,"section1","section2","section2","section10","section1",
                                                             NA,"section10","section3",NA))

mydf <- mydf[order(mydf$section, mydf$name, decreasing=FALSE),]#normal sort on data frame

library(gtools)

sortvar <- mixedsort(mydf$section)#natural sort on variable
sortvar
#NATURAL SORT ON DATAFRAME???
```

I want to obtain a data frame first sorted by "section", and then by "name", using natural sort, like this:

```
   name   section
2     C  section1
6     Z  section1
3     A  section2
4     E  section2
9     G  section3
8     D section10
5     F section10
1     B      <NA>
10    J      <NA>
7     U      <NA>
```

Anybody? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydf[with(mydf, order(as.integer(sub('\\D+', '', section)), name)),]
#   name   section
#2     C  section1
#6     Z  section1
#3     A  section2
#4     E  section2
#9     G  section3
#8     D section10
#5     F section10
#1     B      <NA>
#10    J      <NA>
#7     U      <NA>
```

Comment: of course with sub! easier than I thought... Thanks!